# Java program on "friendly numbers "

Tags: java

I am working on a assignment about so called "friendly-numbers" with the following definition: An integer is said to be friendly if the leftmost digit is divisible by 1, the leftmost two digits are divisible by 2, and the leftmost three digits are divisible by 3, and so on. The n-digit itself is divisible by n.

Also it was given we need to call a method (as I did or at least tried to do in the code below). It should print whether a number is friendly or not. However, my program prints "The integer is not friendly." in both cases. From what I have tried, I know the counter does work. I just cannot find what I am missing or doing wrong. Help would be appreciated, and preferably with an adaptation of the code below, since that is what I came up with myself.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class A5E4 {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please enter an integer: ");
        int friendlyNumber = in.nextInt();
        boolean result = isFriendly(friendlyNumber);
        if (result)
        {
            System.out.println("The integer is friendly");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("The integer is not friendly");
        }
    }
    public static boolean isFriendly(int number)
    {
        int counter = 1;

        while (number / 10 >= 1)
        {
            counter ++;
            number = number / 10;           
        }   

        boolean check = true;

        for (int i = 1; i <= counter; i++)
        {


            if (number / Math.pow(10, (counter - i)) % i == 0 && check)
            {
                check = true;               
            }
            else
            {
                check = false;
            }



        }
        return check;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to copy the number which you use to find out how much digits your number has. Otherwise you change the number itself and don't know anymore what it was.
The second mistake is that you divide an integer by `Math.pow()` which returns a double. So your result is double. You want to have an integer to use the modulo operator.

```
 public static boolean isFriendly(int number)
{
    int counter = 1;
    int tmpNumber = number;
    while (tmpNumber / 10 >= 1)
    {
        counter ++;
        tmpNumber = tmpNumber / 10;
    }

    boolean check = true;

    for (int i = 1; i <= counter; i++)
    {


        if ((int)(number / Math.pow(10, (counter - i))) % i == 0 && check)
        {
            check = true;
        }
        else
        {
            check = false;
        }



    }
    return check;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
while (number / 10 >= 1){
    counter ++;
    number = number / 10;           
}
```

In this bit, you are reducing `number` to something smaller than 10. That is probably not what you want. You should make a copy of `number` here.
Also, proper software design would recommend that you extract this to a dedicated method.

```
private int countDigits(int number){
    if(number < 1) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    int n = number;
    int counter = 1;
    while (n / 10 >= 1){
        counter ++;
        n = n / 10;           
    }
    return counter;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is that you are modifying the value of the number you are trying to check. So, if your method is called with 149, then after the while loop to count the digits, its value will be 1. So, you are always going to find that it is 'unfriendly'. Assuming you fix this so that number contains the number you are checking. Try this instead of your 'for' loop:

```
while ( counter && !( ( number % 10 / counter ) % counter ) )
{
    number = number / 10;
    counter--;
}
```

It works by taking the last digit of your number using the modulus or remainder operator and then divides this by the digit position and checks that the remainder is zero. If all is good, it decrements the counter until it reaches zero, otherwise it terminates before counter is zero.

Comment: Thank you! I get it know. The for loop I was using doesn't work because of what Markus pointed out, that the Math.pow() returns a double thus the modulo doesn't work, right? One last remaining question: if I implement these lines into my program I get the error: the operator ! is undefined for the argument type int. Any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: Try ( ( number % 10 / counter ) % counter ) == 0 instead. The error is because ! is a boolean operator and the expression it is being applied to is int. The version of java I was using to test my suggestion didn't mind, but your's is more strongly typed.

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this (change your `isFriendly()` method):

```
public static boolean isFriendly(int number)
{
    String numberAsString = String.valueOf(number); //Convert the int as a String to make it easier to iterate through

    for(int i = 0; i < numberAsString.length(); i++) {
        int currentDigit = Character.getNumericValue(numberAsString.charAt(numberAsString.length() - i - 1));   //Iterate over the number backwards
        System.out.println(currentDigit);   //Print the current digit
        if(currentDigit % (i + 1) != 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The easy way is to convert to string and then check if it is friendly:

```
public static boolean isFriendly(int number)
{
    String num = Integer.toString(number);
    for (int i = 0, dividedBy = 1; i < num.length(); i++, dividedBy++) 
    {
        String numToCheck = "";
        for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++)
        {
            numToCheck += num.charAt(j);
        }
        if (Integer.valueOf(numToCheck) % dividedBy != 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```